# To prove whether the given set is countable or not

Tags: functions, cardinals

[image]

The function $f(k) = \mathbb{N}^k$ is a one to one function but it is not an onto function. Hence the function is not a one to one correspondence function.

Does that give sufficient justification to proof that the given set in not countable? Or is there any other way to approach the same.

Answer (score 2):

$N^k$ is a set.

You are suppose to show whether a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^k$ exists.

Guide:

You might want to first verify whether the following is true.

If $A$ is countable and $B$ is countable, then their cartesian product $A \times B$ is countable and then you might want to consider using induction.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently $N$ here is the set of all integers, while $k$ is a particular integer.  What do you mean by $f(k) = N^k$?

In any case, one particular function failing to be a one-to-one correspondence is not grounds to conclude that there is no one-to-one correspondence.